# How to add virus/trojan scanning process in CI/CD on Gitlab

Tags: ios, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner, fastlane

i used CI/CD on gitlab runner and build iOS (ipa file) from fastlane on Mac server and deploy to appcenter.
i have pipelines (Lint, Test, Coverage and Deploy)

**Question:**
How to add virus/trojan scanning process in CI/CD
and if I install scan virus tool on Mac server it's help ?

Comment: Do you mean vulnerability scanning? It would be kind of odd to scan for malware in software you build yourself, right?

Comment: Yes, i mean vulnerability scanning sample : https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/automated-scanning-howto?hl=en_US  or https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/ But i don't see support on iOS / Swift file.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/analyzers.html (SAST analyzers) for Free Account)